# How can I have a blue background on a hover even with css?

Tags: html, css

so my navigation bar on mobile looks good apart from the fact that only the drop down links turn blue when hovered over. The normal links don't change the background colour.

Link to site: http://unitycode.github.io/

How can I make it so each link in my mobile collapse menu has a blue background once hovered on?

I have tried the normal way of doing this, but it has not made an effect.

Id like Home, Blog & Forum to have  that blue background when hovered over when the navbar is collapsed.

Normal link format:

```
<li class="dropdown-surface"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

Drop down link format:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Resources</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left animated-2x animated fadeIn">
     <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="has_children">About us &amp; Team</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
      <li><a href="page_about.html">About us Option 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="page_about2.html">About us Option 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="page_about3.html">About us &amp; Team</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="page_team.html">Our Team Option 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="page_team2.html">Our Team Option 2</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

CSS:

```css
/* ---------------------------------------------------- */
/* Navbar */
/* ---------------------------------------------------- */
.navbar-default {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ececec, #f4f4f4);
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-family: "Muli", sans-serif;
  word-spacing: -6px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0;
  background-image: url("../img/colors/blue/logo.png");
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 45px;
  color: #000;
}
@media (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    background: none !important;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand span {
  color: #0099da;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-menu li a .label {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 8px;
}
.dropdown-menu li a:hover .label {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #0099da;
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  /*Navbar Collapse*/
  .navbar-collapse {
    padding: 0;
  }
  /*Navbar*/
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown > a {
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    background-color: #0099da;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #0087c1, #0099da);
    color: #fff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    background-color: #0099da;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #0087c1, #0099da);
    color: #fff;
  }
  /*Dropdown Menu*/
  .dropdown-menu {
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 200px;
    border-radius: 0;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }
  .dropdown-menu li a {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 6px 15px;
  }
  .dropdown-menu .active > a,
  .dropdown-menu li > a:hover,
  .dropdown-menu li > a:focus,
  .dropdown-menu li > a:active {
    background-color: #0099da;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #0087c1, #0099da);
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown > a {
    padding-right: 25px;
  }
  .dropdown > a:after {
    right: 10px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.9em;
    word-spacing: -5px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0;
    background-image: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
}
.navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: #555;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #4d4d4d, #666);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
  height: 51px;
  min-width: 45px;
}
.navbar-header .navbar-toggle i {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.sb-icon-navbar i {
  background-color: #555;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #4d4d4d, #666);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 11px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 15px 14px 14px 14px;
  height: 50px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 842px) {
  .navbar-right {
    float: left !important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .sb-icon-navbar i {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    word-spacing: -4px;
    margin-left: 60px;
  }
}
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-inverse a {
  color: #fff;

}
.dropdown.dropdown-inverse a:hover{
  color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #0087c1, #0099da);
}
.dropdown.dropdown-inverse ul {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #222;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0 0 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
.dropdown.dropdown-inverse .divider {
  background-color: #555;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-inverse .dropdown-header {
  border-color: #555;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #ccc;
}
.dropdown > a:after,
.dropdown-submenu > a:after {
  top: 8px;
  right: 9px;
  font-size: 11px;
  content: "\f105";
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
.dropdown > a:after {
  top: 18px;
  right: 15px;
  content: "\f107";
}
.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
  top: -1px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .dropdown > a {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .dropdown.open > a,
  .dropdown.open > a:focus,
  .dropdown.open > a:active {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
  }
  .dropdown-surface{
    border-top: solid 1px #555;
    }
  .dropdown a {
    padding: 0 6px;
  }
  .dropdown-submenu {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: -5px;
  }
  .dropdown-submenu a {
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-submenu > a:after {
    content: " ";
  }
  .dropdown > a:after {
    top: 10px;
    right: 15px;
    content: "\f104";
  }
  .dropdown.open > a:after {
    top: 10px;
    right: 15px;
    content: "\f107";
  }
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}
.dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.dropdown-header {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
  border-top: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
  padding: 6px 0;
  margin: 9px 0;
}
```

http://postimg.org/image/o6kijxs0n/ = Only the drop down links have a blue background when you hover over them but id like the normal links (Home,Blog and Forum) to have the same blue background too when you hover over them

Comment: Can you please add a code? Cause if you dont we really cant help you.......

Comment: @ewrwr added the HTML but i cant post the css because there's alot (6000+ lines).

Comment: @JackSewell we just need the relevant css parts

Comment: Im in need of help ASAP :(

Comment: it's unclear what you realy want. You should totaly rephrase your question

Comment: Changed title and add question in OG post.

Comment: I still don't get it - screenshot?

Comment: Done @CodeiSir Id like the notrmal links to have the same hover background

Comment: The problem about this question was to get to the point you actually wanted. In a normal window you will never get what you see in your screenshot, thats why we could not find what you want

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```css
.navbar-nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #0099da !important;
}
```